# How Do I delete repository using GITBlit ? What should be the serverUrl?

Tags: gitblit

I know when we create a repository we have to give the repo server URL as

baseUrl + "rpc?req=CREATE_REPOSITORY&name="+ repoName;

when we delete the repo is it

baseUrl + "rpc?req=DELETE_REPOSITORY&name="+ repoName;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DELETE_REPOSITORY request (for Gitblit <= v1.3.2) requires a JSON body (repository model) on the post.  The name parameter is unused.  You could probably define a really minimal body that only specified the repository name, but I haven't tested that.

```
{
"name": "libraries/xmlapache-renamed.git"
}
```